# Can Dart be used as a general-purpose language?

Tags: dart, dart-native-extension

Dart supports interfacing with the native libraries (Ref: http://www.dartlang.org/articles/native-extensions-for-standalone-dart-vm/). There are some decent libraries available for socket communication, interfacing with databases and dealing with filesystems. Barring desktop GUI applications, I don't see any reason why it cannot be used as a general purpose language. What are advantages/disadvantages of Dart being used as a general purpose language (including performance)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. Dart can be used as a general purpose programming language.

Advantages:

- It's [fast](http://www.dartlang.org/performance/), already faster than V8, and catching up to the JVM (Though
  it starts up much quicker).
- It's great for scripting on macos/linux. You can prefix a source file with #!/usr/bin/env dart
- Backed by a large team/company who are developing it in the open, along with an [active community](http://dartlang.org/mailing-list).
- Good [documentation](http://api.dartlang.org/) and [articles](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/).

Disadvantages:

- It's new. There are far more libraries available for Java, Python and node.js than for Dart.
- There are likely to be changes to the core IO libraries before it hits 1.0.
- No built-in support on cloud-hosting platforms, though there is a [heroku buildpack](https://github.com/igrigorik/heroku-buildpack-dart).

Note you can build GUI applications using dart2js and chrome packaged apps.

Comment: "fast, already faster than V8, and catching up to the JVM". Did you just describe beating Javascript as "fast". :-)